# Highlight specific line of output

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm building a piece of educational software and I have pseudocode on the output where I would like to highlight a specific line of code depending on which piece of code is running.

```
First round()
.....
```

--> highlight this line and the next after it moves
Output: First round has just started

The furthest I got was doing some bash highlighting but that required me to print out the line twice. Once in black and second in a different colour. Any suggestions on how to highlight a specific line? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I'm using Pyqt as my GUI toolkit so my output will be displayed in a textbox

Comment: This question gives no context about what your allowed technologies are, besides the implication that a shell is okay. Please edit your question to be clearer. If a shell is all you have to work with, you can use a curses display, or clear the screen each time you change the highlights (resulting in flicker probably).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the `QTextBlock` object that correspond to the line (*) you want to highlight or unhighlight and use a `QTextCursor` to change the format of that line:

```
def setLineFormat(self, lineNumber, format):
    cursor = QTextCursor(self.textEdit.document().findBlockByNumber(lineNumber))
    cursor.setBlockFormat(format)     

# with
format = QTextBlockFormat()
format.setBackground(Qt.yellow)
# or
format.clearBackground()
```

If you are using `QSyntaxHighlighter`, you could also store the state of the line in the `QTextBlock` with `QTextBlock.setUserState()` or `setUserData`, handle that state in the `QSyntaxHighlighter.highlightBlock()` method as part of the syntax highlighting, and force the previous and the current lines to be repainted with `QSyntaxHighlighter.rehighlightBlock()`.

<sub>*: lines==blocks unless you use a custom document layout</sub>